# Consume JSON streaming uploads with Quarkus

Tags: java, json, quarkus

Is there a way to implement a JSON streaming upload using Quarkus, with akka-http it is readable and easy to understand see [example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.2/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#consuming-json-streaming-uploads)

So what i want is to send a sequence of json objects to my Quarkus web app and process each json object without accumulating the whole sequence in memory then return a response that contains the number of processed objects.

So far i only found an example of a [streamed response](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#streaming-json-array-items) based on vertx:

```java
@Route(path = "/people")
Multi<Person> people(RoutingContext context) {
    return ReactiveRoutes.asJsonArray(Multi.createFrom().items(
            new Person("superman", 1),
            new Person("batman", 2),
            new Person("spiderman", 3)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive#handling-streams explains you can inded do the same with `quarkus-resteasy`:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/people")
public Multi<Person> greetings() {
  return Multi.createFrom().items(
            new Person("superman", 1),
            new Person("batman", 2),
            new Person("spiderman", 3));
}
```